# OpenGL Core profile - Array of arrays in glBufferData for VBOs

Tags: opengl, vbo

I want to send each face as VBO, and I structured the data as this

```
facevbo[0] =  x x x x x x   //x,y,z,r,g,b,s,t
facevbo[1] =  x x x x x
facevbo[2] =  x x x x x x x 
facevbo[3] =  x x x x
.
.
.
facevbo[numfaces] = x x x x
```

Basicly I have dynamic 2d array with different column size:

```
GLfloat** faceVBO = new GLfloat*[m_numOfFaces];
faceVBO[dfaceIndex] = new GLfloat[pFace->numOfVerts*8];
```

When I print all the faces, everything is fine, 
but when im trying to put them to use,
i have problem at this line:
(ideally I would iterate trough all the faces to bind each face, but lets take the first column)

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*oindices, faceVBO[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

the third parameter (faceVBO[0])
"argument of type GLfloat is incompatible with param. of type const void*"

but if i tead from array, like

```
GLfloat facevbo[] = {x,x,x,x...}
```

and

```
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*oindices, faceVBO, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

it works OK.
How should i send the data in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you need an array of pointers? This seems unnecessary.

Comment: Seemed like logical solution...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing an address value to data rather than the data itself.  A naive solution is to change:

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*oindices, faceVBO[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

to:

`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4*oindices, *faceVBO[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);`

To clarify: in your implementation, 'faceVBO' is a pointer to a set of pointers, and glBufferData() requires a pointer to the data, so sending it 'faceVBO[0]' directly is an attempt to send the pointer to the data as the data itself, which is incorrect.

Comment: `*faceVBO[0]` is a `GLfloat`, not a ptr

Comment: @tkausl Actually, it is the first of (pFace->numOfVerts*8) floats, according to the OP's code, but that's just nitpicking; the fact is that faceVBO[0] itself is a pointer (whether to one or more floats) and not the actual data required by the function.

Comment: I just saw that in the header file I already mistakenly defined `GLfloat *faceVBO;`. So I removed it and now accepts `faceVBO[0]`... and  `&faceVBO[0]` ,also???

Comment: That is because &faceVBO[0] is a reference to faceVBO[0], used often in C++11. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B) for an explanation.

Comment: `&faceVBO[0]` is definitely wrong. `faceVBO[0]` might be right but not sure since you only fill `faceVBO[dfaceIndex]` and i do not know what `dfaceIndex` is. But as i said in my other comment to your question, it shouldn't be necessary to use a array of ptr's

Comment: I have a loop that goes trough all the faces from dfaceIndex=0 to numofFaces. What do You suggest to use? Vectors?

Comment: @tkausl Agree with you on the use of & there, as well as the use of pointer arrays (which are inherently unsafe). For 'faceVBO[dfaceIndex]', my assumption was that 'dfaceIndex' is incremented for each face and the OP's post was in the interest of brevity (just confirmed).

Comment: I use vectors in my engine (which is also highly dynamic with regards to geometry), so yes, that would be a viable option; in that case, you could use a vector::data() call to glBufferData(), and faceFBO could be a vector of vectors..

Comment: `and faceFBO could be a vector of vectors` no, then you'll have the same problem again. just a plain vector of GLfloat or a vector of `Vertex` if he has a struct `Vertex`.

Comment: @tkausl My bad, I slightly misread the context and ran ahead of myself. <.< You are right, a single vector is fine.

Comment: So what you guys suggest is to have separate vectors = numFaces, and in each vector to store the data?

Comment: That would depend on your rendering method; are you wanting a single VBO to hold all faces and batch them all at once, or do your faces need to be rendered separately (due to different textures per face)? For example, with one vector the first works outright, the second if you are happy to upload more data than you actually index per shader call (which is often a reasonable tradeoff, since the vertex data is in the GPU for the next draw call). Implementation details are subjective based on the required capabilities of your rendering pipeline; you need to find one that works best for you.